# Empty CSS code functionality

Tags: html, css

I'm having this really strange issue with CSS:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{}
    
.checker{
 display: none !important;
        /*left: -9999px;*/
        /*opacity: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" checked/>
<label for="labelCheck" class="checker"></label>
<label class="create">Subscribe to our awesome newsletter</label><br/>
```

The reason I wish to hide the checkbox is that I want to create a custom one, but for finding this error, I tried commenting out all other code, so I only had this stuff left.

The strange thing is this:
It works.... These bits of code makes a hidden checkbox.
But if I delete this line from the CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{}
```

then the checkbox becomes visible again. Why is my code affected by a piece of code that does nothing (empty function) ?

The reason I have the other pieces of commented-out-code is just to tell you guys that I already searched the forum and found the following solutions to hide it:

- !important
- left: -9999px
- opacity: 0

.... none of which worked...

testing with Chrome..

Comment: Comments in CSS are written like this : `/* Comment */`

Comment: Fair enough - that's what I used for commenting out everything else; I just assumed the other would work as well, since Netbeans accepted it.
Anyway; that still doesn't solve the mystery of how this has any functionality, when it's still an empty function...?

Comment: So it works now? Or still having the same problem?

Comment: `//` is a parse error, not a comment. CSS attempts to recover from these errors, but it doesn't always work like you might expect. Removing that line from CSS doesn't make the checkbox visible for me.

Comment: No, I still don't get why the empty "function" has some kind of effect. It needs to be there for the checkbox to be hidden, if I remove it, the checkbox reappears...
I updated the question to reflect this problem as the real one.

Comment: @Henry Please add another snippet which shows that effect. It works as expected for me, the checkbox remains hidden.

Comment: @Oriol works for me too

Comment: I can see that it works fine when I click the text button in the post, but I tried this just running the documents in both Chrome and Safari, and the problem remains in both...

Comment: @Henry If you can't reproduce it here that means the issue is somewhere else in your CSS, look for styles affecting the checkbox with your browser's inspector.

Comment: Okay, so I found out what caused it, and it was my whole commenting thing... I used // instead of /* a different place in the style sheet, and that was enough to somehow cause some trouble.

Comment: Well that's a surprising user name to see! We should start a club or something